# Formatting Numbers in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following number sequence

```
id
----
1
2
3
4
5
```

I need the id values in below format

```
10
100
1000
10000
100000
```

This means based on the id column values I want the same number of zeros in right side.

Comment: What do you want - numbers or text values?

Comment: @Zhorov I want numbers

Comment: You cannot have numbers because of type limitations. Read this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 
You have an answer which could be your solution, posted by Thiyagu

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach is the following statement using `REPLICATE()` to repeat the character `0`:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Data (id int)
INSERT INTO Data (id) VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5)
```

Statement

```
SELECT CONCAT('1', REPLICATE('0', id)) AS id
FROM Data
```

Result:

```
id
10
100
1000
10000
100000
```

Notes:

Use `CONCAT()` to avoid `null` results in the output if you have `null` values in the `ìd` column. If this is not important, `'1' + REPLICATE('0', id)` is also an option.

If you want the results as [numeric](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/numeric-types?view=sql-server-ver15) data type (int, bigint, smallint, tinyint, numeric), you need to convert the results, but consider the range for each data type to avoid `arithmetic overflow` error.

```
SELECT CONVERT(int, CONCAT('1', REPLICATE('0', id))) AS id
FROM Data
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`POWER()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/power-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
SELECT
    id,
    POWER(id, 10) AS output
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY id;
```

Note that for values of `id` greater than around 20, the resulting exponent value would not even fit into a big int column.

Comment: POWER(10, id) perhaps, but is limited to type, because arithmetic overflow will be reached...

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (ID INT)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES(1)
INSERT INTO @T VALUES(2)
INSERT INTO @T VALUES(3)
INSERT INTO @T VALUES(4)
INSERT INTO @T VALUES(5)


SELECT *,CONCAT(1,REPLICATE(0,ID)) AS SEQ
FROM @T
```

Comment: please check out the code formatting option of the editor.

Answer (score 1):

Can we do?

```
with tb(cl) as(
    select 1 union all
    select 2 union all
    select 3 union all
    select 4 union all
    select 5  
)
select 
    cast ( SUBSTRING('10000000000',1, cl+1) as int) as id
from tb
```

Comment: Or `Left( '10000000000', cl + 1 )`. Can step up to `bigint` if `int` doesn't suffice.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following query using `REPLICATE()` function.

```
Select id
   , '1' + REPLICATE('0', id)
from Data
```

[image]
Live [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e6f8cb319d43ca6f73cd6c600a665795) demo.